# find a string and extract the full row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id   string     value
3    hello      23
7    bee        90
```

I want to search the whole data frame for "hello" in the string column and return the full row where it is present, along with the index. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataframe using the following;

```
df[df['string']=='hello']
```

where df is the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

To get the row matching an exact string you can use @Aanish's proposition.
If you want to return every row for which the `string` column contains a specific string you can use the `str.contain()` method:

```
r = df[df['string'].str.contains('hello')]
```

To get the index of the rows just use the `.index` method

```
index = r.index.to_list()
```

which is equivalent to doing : `df.index[df['string'].str.contains('hello')]`

You can then create a list of tuples with your index and the corresponding row using list comprehensions:

```
output = [(index[i],r.loc[index[i]]) for i in range(len(index))]
```